# I want all number that is starts with 419 in a cell will be '419, this is to prevent the last number for being 0

Tags: excel, vba

I need a code for excel vba code. I want to have all numbers in a cell that starts in 419, the cell will have an ' in front like this '419 and my cell looks like this 419312312331,4191231231231,419123123 because it always replaces the last number with a zero.

I'm just using this macro

```
Set Rng = ActiveCell Cells.Replace What:="419", Replacement:="'419", LookAt:=xlPart, _ SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _ ReplaceFormat:=False
```

it will replace all the numbers that have 419 but I only want the numbers that start in 419. This number is a serial number in a sim that has multiple serial numbers in a single cell so I'm struggling to get the 1st 419's in the serial

[image]

Comment: im just using this macro

Set Rng = ActiveCell
    Cells.Replace What:="419", Replacement:="'419", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

but it will replace all the number that hvae 419 i want the numbers only starts in 419 this number are serial number in a sim it have maultiple serial number in a single cell so im struggling getting the 1st 419's in the serial

Comment: Why VBA? you can insert a blank column and use a formula `If()` and `Left()` to achieve what you want...

Comment: i put image in my post please check it i will encounter many of that so i dont want to manually put formula everytime

Comment: also because after replacing 419 to '419 i will split all those imei into rows thats the situation were excel auto formats the last number into zero

Comment: Then use `IF` and `Left` in VBA code and then replace them.

Comment: it will only get the 1st IMEI the IMEI after "," will not replaced

Comment: So look for `,419` and replace it with `,'419`

Comment: thats very helpful sir im releaved a lot, but the first IMEI will now not replaced. cause it dont have ","

Comment: Can you post the code that you have tried using IF and LEFT?

Comment: I dont try IF and LEFT yet Im using the code above on the comments thats only recorded macro to FIND and REPLACE 419's. Honestly Not really familiar coding in excel